# Возможно ли, чтобы UV растягивалась автоматически с изменением меша в Blender?

Tags: python, blender

Есть меш, текстурированный текстурой тротуарной плитки, нужно сделать множество копий этого меша и каждая копия должна иметь свои уникальные размеры, сделав эти уникальные размеры у каждой копии нужно вручную изменять UV-сетку, чтобы вновь текстура легла как надо. Почти решение для автоматизации этого дела (для подгона текстур) есть - использовать ноды - "Geometry" и "Mapping", но оно применимо только в Blender, а мне **нужно экспортировать эти модели с правильно подогнанными текстурами в Unity**, а для этого нужно, чтобы при изменении меша автоматически изменялась и UV этого меша. Ну и вопрос следующий из этого: **возможно ли, чтобы UV растягивалась автоматически с изменением меша в Blender?**

Может как-то на Python можно запрограммировать... вроде, не должно там быть очень сложно, просто изменять значения UV сетки с изменением меша, но, конечно, нужно знать Python, в Blender библиотеках разобраться, а я знаю C#, но если кто здесь подскажет куда нужно щупать, то сам бы попробовал написать.
Благодарю за прочтение, надеюсь на помощь, ибо не первый вопрос касающийся этого дела.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть замечательный аддон от 3Dmaster Sure UV Map. Он как раз подходит для создания разверток на стенах и прочих поверхностях с одинаковым масштабом. Мне кажется, это то, что вам нужно:

https://3dmaster.ru/downloads/

А то что вы описываете похоже на одну из функций аддона Magic UV. Он входит в базовую поставку блендера

Так-же есть модификатор Project UV, который генерирует UV карту проецируя ее из камеры или из Empty

Comment: Спасибо за такой развёрнутый ответ. Скорее всего, это и есть решение!